# Suddenly: Service using too much computer time for one day

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, quota

I have been putting out fires all day. Can't seem to make heads or tails of this error...

Today I started for the first time after months of using the same script. It is triggered when a new record is added to a google sheet.

It seems to work on and off but every few minutes I am getting a failure notice indicating "Service using too much computer time for one day".

Looking through the documentation and the post on Stack, it is clear I am not the first to deal with this issue, but there does not seem to be any concise answer to how to resolve. I looked for some way to reach some type of google assistance but am always directed back to stack overflow to submit my issue for consideration. Understand this could be an issue with my script, but cant seem to find what might be causing this issue. Also confusing the matter is that the script does seem to be firing 90% of the time.

My questions:

1. How do I check the "computer time" quota?
2. Should I turn off that script/trigger until 24 hours have passed?
3. Does anyone know how to get a hold of Google support directly?

Comment: About `It is triggered when a new record is added to a google sheet.`, what trigger are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way that the total script run time can be seen in a dashboard.
You can see duration times of individual script executions at:
https://script.google.com/home/executions

You could scroll through your executions to look for long durations times.  That might indicate an endless loop in your code.

To calculate the total run time of all your running scripts, you'd need to use the Apps Script API.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/view-processes
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts/processes

I don't have any code to list and compile all the durations.
If anyone does, that would be very interesting.

I don't know if deleting the trigger until the next day would gain you anything.  I'm guessing that it shouldn't.

Google does not provide "on demand" support people to answer questions about Apps Script.  Even G Suite customers don't get "on demand" support contacts for Apps Script.  You can report bugs and request features through the Google Issue Tracker, but that won't get you direct contact with a Google support person.  Even if you purchase a support plan, Google doesn't have people who are designated to support Apps Script.  If you purchased a support plan, they might try to help you with an Apps Script question, but officially they aren't qualified to help, or obligated to provide Apps Script support.  And even if a support person tries to help you with an Apps Script problem, the first thing they'll do is a search of Stack Overflow, and give you links to SO posts.

So, it's extremely unlikely that you're going to be able to talk with someone directly at Google.

The best thing to do is to review your code for performance issues.  Avoid reading the writing data often.  The ideal situation is to get all the data that you need just once, process it, and write it back once.  Cache data if you can.  Avoid lots of calls to Properties Service.  Find what part of your code is taking the longest time, and try to improve it.